# How to define datasource properties for WildFly bootable JAR without openshift CLI?

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss, wildfly

So normally you could use the standalone.xml to do this, but the [wildfly bootable JAR](https://docs.wildfly.org/bootablejar/) seems not to have a standalone.xml since it's all within a single JAR.

The examples that JBoss provides assume you'll only ever use OpenShift for some reason and uses some arcane OpenShift CLI command (below) that just somehow creates the right file in the right spot.  https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-jar-maven-plugin/tree/4.0.0.Final/examples/postgresql

```
oc new-app --name database-server \
  --env POSTGRESQL_USER=admin \
  --env POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=admin \
  --env POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=sampledb \
  postgresql
```

However, there is no config file created with that command (or they didnt check it in), and the documentation doesn't say anything about how to do the same for non-OpenShift projects.

Trying to find any info on how to do configure a (postgres) data-source for a non-OpenShift deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out on my own with some experimentation. WildFly documentation on bootable jars is still really minimal and lacking lots of detail that required lots of guessing / experimenting.

While there is an overlay that lets you specify DB info via environment variables, that's a bit hacky and doesn't allow you to define more than one datasource nor can you specify the JNDI name.  Instead, I used a CLI script which gets fed into the jar builder plugin.

**datasource.cli**

```
data-source add --name=<name> --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/<schema> --driver-name=postgresql --connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<db> --user-name=<user> --password=<pass>
```

Make sure to use your own values for placeholders <name>, <schema>, <db>, <user>, <pass> and swap out the hostname / port if needed.

**pom.xml (snippet)**

```
<configuration>
    <cli-sessions>
        <cli-session>
            <script-files>
                <script>scripts/datasource.cli</script>
            </script-files>
            <resolve-expressions>true</resolve-expressions>
        </cli-session>
    </cli-sessions>
    <feature-packs>
        <feature-pack>
            <location>wildfly@maven(org.jboss.universe:community-universe)#23.0.0.Final</location>
        </feature-pack>
        <feature-pack>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
        </feature-pack>
    </feature-packs>
    <layers>
        <layer>jaxrs-server</layer>
        <layer>postgresql-driver</layer>
    </layers>
</configuration>
```

In the above XML config, items of note are

1. <script> value tells the builder where to find the CLI script that will do the datasource adding
2. <feature-pack> for the datasource pack. Though I didn't test if this was required...  maybe the driver layer is all that's needed.  Worth trying if you have time.
3. <layer> that specifies the postgresql-driver value. This is required and without it, the bootup will complain about missing a driver when the CLI script runs.

Comment: Thank you! I was suffering with that for a whole day

Comment: how do you replace those placeholders, for example, <db>?

Comment: @VictorBello those placeholders aren't valid syntax.  I just put them in there for the sake of posting it to stackoverflow.  you'd have to figure out something on your own if you want string substitution

Comment: Thanks @Wisteso, Actually I found out. You can use ${env.NAME_VARIABLE} and replace it using enviroment variables...

Answer (score 0):

A bit late (and I'm not allowed to comment rn), but JFTR: you can even use the proposed "datasource" `<layer>` as advertised in
https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack/tree/main

So you choose, for example,

```xml
<configuration>
    <featurePacks>
        <featurePack>
            <location>wildfly@maven(org.jboss.universe:community-universe)</location>
        </featurePack>
        <feature-pack>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.datasources.galleon-pack}</version>
        </feature-pack>
    </featurePacks>
    <layers>
        ...
        <layer>postgresql-datasource</layer>
        ....
```

And start the resulting jar via

```bash
POSTGRESQL_USER=user POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password java -jar your-bootable.jar
```

These two Properties are the bare minimum to set. The complete list of possible configuration properties is found in
https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack/blob/main/doc/postgresql/README.md (and the corresponding chapters for the chosen database `<layer>`).

This way you can dynamicaly change the databases without changing your build (a question, [Victor Bello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66998791/how-to-define-datasource-properties-for-wildfly-bootable-jar-without-openshift-c#comment130600388_67023668) asked in the above comments)

**Drawback**

The only drawback of this path is, you can't have more than one datasource from the same layer.
So I chose your path and added two `datasource add ...`lines.

Thanks for this